# How can I prevent URL from containing %0A%0D in Java, in order to mitigate XSS attacks?

Tags: java, servlets, xss

My URL looks like the following:
`http://example.com/value=S%0a%0d"><'script>alert(0)<'/script'>%20"`

When I print value of the `value` request parameter in my Servlet, using the following code:

```
String Value=request.getParameter("value");

System.out.print("URL :"+Value);
```

The output is as follows:

```
URL :S

"><'script>alert(0)<'/script'>%20
```

It printed two lines (which makes this possibly vulnerable to XSS attacks). I tried the code below to replace the `%0A%0D` characters:

```
Value = value.replace('\n', ' ');
Value = value.replace('\r', ' ');
Value = value.replace("\n", "");
value = value.replace("\r", "");
value = value.replaceAll("0A", "");
value = value.replaceAll("0D", "");
value = value.replaceAll("%0A", "");
value = value.replaceAll("%0D", "");
value = value.replaceAll("%0A%0D", "");
```

But it only checks the first line of the output. How can I remove these characters from the URL, in order to mitigate XSS attacks?

Answer (score 1):

To protect against XSS, I would advise *against* a character by character replace as you have used in the example snippet. You are bound to forget something from your list of characters you are substituting and you application may continue to be vulnerable.

Instead, I would recommend using: 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project

Comment: I can't able to use third party library.Is there any other solution?

Comment: The project mentioned above is opensource. If you do not want to use it directly, you could refer to the code and replicate/duplicate the code as you like. Source code: https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-encoder/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

In summary the correct approach would be to encode all chars appropriately instead of having code that replaces unsafe chars.